# How to get DisplayAttribute of a property by Reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, reflection

I have a Helper method like this to get me the PropertyName (trying to avoid magic strings)

```
public static string GetPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression)
        {
            var body = (MemberExpression) expression.Body;
            return body.Member.Name;
        }
```

However sometimes my PropertyNames aren't named well either. So I would like to rather use the DisplayAttribute.

```
[Display(Name = "Last Name")]
public string Lastname {get; set;}
```

Please be aware I am using Silverlight 4.0.  I couldnt find the usual namespace  DisplayAttributeName attribute for this.

How can I change my method to read the attribute (if available) of th eproperty instead?

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This should work:

```
public static string GetPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression)
{
    MemberExpression propertyExpression = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
    MemberInfo propertyMember = propertyExpression.Member;

    Object[] displayAttributes = propertyMember.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), true);
    if(displayAttributes != null && displayAttributes.Length == 1)
        return ((DisplayAttribute)displayAttributes[0]).Name;

    return propertyMember.Name;
}
```

Comment: If you are using resource files you will need to use the `GetName()` method, not just the `Name` property i.e. the 2nd last line would be return `((DisplayAttribute)displayAttributes[0]).GetName();`

Comment: The null check for displayAttributes != null is probably not needed here, as GetCustomAttributes always returns an object[]