# WPF and binding ToolTip to a DisplayAttribute

Tags: wpf, binding

In my view model, I have added DisplayAttributes to my properties, and would now like to bind the ToolTip property of my TextBox controls to the Description property of the DisplayAttribute.

I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499459/how-to-get-displayattribute-of-a-property-by-reflection) which handles the reading of the description, but can't figure out how to populate the ToolTip using the calculated description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a roundabout way to do this since WPF doesn't support this attribute and so you'll be entering the attributes into the view-model and the view-model will be looking them up.  They could be in any internal format.

In any case, here is a demo of the problem as you've stated it.  We add a `Descriptions` property to the class that the text boxes are bound to.  That property is a dictionary that maps property names to descriptions, that is, attributes.  In the static constructor for the view-model we look up all the attributes and populate the dictionary.

A small XAML file with two text boxes:

```
<Grid >
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName}" ToolTip="{Binding Descriptions[FirstName]}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding LastName}" ToolTip="{Binding Descriptions[LastName]}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

the code-behind:

```
        DataContext = new DisplayViewModel();
```

and a rudimentary view-model with two properties:

```
public class DisplayViewModel
{
    private static Dictionary<string, string> descriptions;

    static DisplayViewModel()
    {
        descriptions = new Dictionary<string,string>();
        foreach (var propertyName in PropertyNames)
        {
            var property = typeof(DisplayViewModel).GetProperty(propertyName);
            var displayAttributes = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), true);
            var displayAttribute = displayAttributes.First() as DisplayAttribute;
            var description = displayAttribute.Name;
            descriptions.Add(propertyName, description);
        }
    }

    public DisplayViewModel()
    {
        FirstName = "Bill";
        LastName = "Smith";
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> PropertyNames { get { return new[] { "FirstName", "LastName" }; } }

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public IDictionary<string, string> Descriptions { get { return descriptions; } }
}
```

Comment: That works nicely, thanks! DisplayAttribute exposes two properties, Name (which is for the UI) and Description (which describes the Name), which is what I am using for tooltips (I was thinking of using Name for the Label, but that means you lose the design-time value for the Name, which is not worth the trouble). If you are going to use Description, be sure to use GetDescription() to read it, since it will evaluate any use of resource strings (via the ResourceType property).